# Помощь с боковым меню

Tags: html, css

хочу сделать бокове меню, чтобы при наведении на ссылку выскакивал блок с подпунктами, однако при наведении на любую из ссылок выскакивают все 3 блока, наложенных друг на друга. Как сделать так, чтобы для каждой ссылки выскакивал свой блок?

```css
.navigation-block {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
}

.product-menu {
    
    background: #ccffff;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    
    
   
}
.product-menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.product-menu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.product-list a {
    display: block;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    
    border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    
}

.product-list a:hover {
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    
}
.product-list {
    
    position: relative;
}

.product-list-drop {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    left: 100%;
    top: -9999em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
}

.product-list:hover .product-list-drop {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="navigation-block">
                    <div class="product-menu">
                        <ul class="product-list">
                                
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
                                <div class="product-list-drop">
                                   
                                </div>
                            
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
                                <div class="product-list-drop">
                                    

                                </div></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
                                <div class="product-list-drop">
                                   
                                    
                                </div></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так ?

```css
.ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.ul_li{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.ul_li:hover{
  color: red;
}

.ul2{
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
} 
.ul_block{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.ul_li:hover .ul_block{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ul_li2{
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.ul_li2:hover{
  color: red;
}
.a{
  position: relative;
}
.a:hover .ul2{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="ul_li">меню1
  <ul class='ul_block'>
    <li class='a'>
      <span>sadadad</span>
      <ul class='ul2'>
        <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню1</li>
        <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню2</li>
        <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ul_li">меню2
  <ul class='ul2'>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню1</li>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню2</li>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ul_li">меню3
  <ul class='ul2'>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню1</li>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню2</li>
    <li class="ul_li2">новый пункт меню3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.S. по этой ссылке Вы найдете больше инфы ... https://html5book.ru/vypadayushee-menu/

Comment: Не совсем так, при наведении должна появляться большая панелька, гораздо больше бокового меню и в ней будут подпункты. В твоем варианте когда курсор наводишь по горизонтале на уровень другой ссылки, то открывается другой список, а нужно, чтобы панель открывалась только при наведении на саму ссылку и для каждой ссылки чтобы была своя.

Comment: @NoobDeveloper меню 1 смотрите так ? Как я понял что Вы хотите сделать называется мега меню вот нашел в интернете https://edithtm.html5css.ru/index.php

Comment: https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.php

Answer (score -2):

Сделай всё этот как отдельный div и указывай классы. Ты сделал свою работу в одном классе с product-menu, проверь это.